# Magento2 - Full page cache issue with multiple stores

Tags: full-page-cache, magento-2.2.5

I have multiple storeviews for my Magento2 website. It is working fine until Full Page cache enabled from `Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Full Page Cache -> Built-in Cache`

The issue is that the storeviews are mixed up when FPC enabled. For example, sometimes my USA website are displaying products from EUR site under some categories (random categories). I need to clear the cache `php bin/magento cache:flush` to get the products showing correctly again. But the problem will come back again after a while.

How can I fix this?

---

Update,

This has something to do with a 3rd party GEO IP module I installed. Once I disable the module. Full page caching is working properly again. But I have not figured out how to get GEO IP module working togaher with Full Page Cache yet.

Comment: Are you using any kind of Proxy setup? I have a similar problem, but behind a NGINX reverse proxy.

Comment: @Alex thanks, I found it out, the issue is actually similar to proxy.  I'm using a Geo IP module, which conflicts with fullpage cache. Once I disabled the GEO IP module. everything looks good again.

Comment: So you do not need the GEO IP module at all? My problem is with SetEndIf: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246503/apache-setenfif-and-fullpage-cache-start-page-shows-the-same-store-view-for-all

If you have deeper insight, why not post an answer to your or my question :-)

Comment: @Alex I actually wanted GEO IP. But so far, I need to disable it in order for full page cache to work properly. I haven't figured out how to fix GEO IP yet.